# Replace String with Regexp for a value fetched from MySQL Query in Robot framework

Tags: mysql, regex, selenium, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am Working in Robot Framework with My SQL Database. I am struck up at a point where I need to Run a Query that returns only one value and use it in UI application.

```
Connect To Database    pymysql    Schema     Username    Password     localhost      portnumber
${result}=    DatabaseLibrary.Query     query
Disconnect From Database
```

In the Report I can see the variable `${result}= ((11111111,),)`

I need that `11111111` and input in the UI application. I Have tried using `Get Substring`, `Replace String with RegExp` but it failing either it returns `((11111111,),)` or string buffer error or typo error.

How can I rewrite to fetch the numeric value to reuse in my code?.

Answer (score 1):

The response from DB queries is list of tuples (that comes from the underlying python implementation) - a list member is a row in the response, the tuple members are the columns in it.

Thus, to get the value of the first column in the first response row, you could do this:

```
${value}=    Set Variable    ${result[0][0]}
```

The indices are 0-based, so if you want the 3rd column from the 2nd row, that would be

```
${value}=    Set Variable    ${result[1][2]}
```